# Add current user to NLog output

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to add a string to each row on my NLog output. The logic stays the same, trying to get the current user and if succeed, add the current user to the output.

I know how to implement it each time, but I want to set this template at one place and not repeat it on each writing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `WindowsIdentityLayoutRenderer` should probably give you what you want.  You can choose to log either the Domain, the UserName, or both.

You would configure it something like this (untested) to your NLog.config file:

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" 
        layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${windows-identity} | ${message}"
        fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log" />
</targets>
```

This might not work in a low privilege environment.

How do you get the user name now?  If you get it something like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Then you can use NLog's "aspnet-user-identity" LayoutRenderer, something like this:

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" 
        layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${aspnet-user-identity} | ${message}"
        fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log" />
</targets>
```

NLog's aspnet* LayoutRenderers are in NLog.Extended.sll, so you will need that dll in addition to NLog.dll.

Comment: My authentication is based on form authentication. any suggestion?

Comment: Is that ASP.NET?  I have not done any development using that, but NLog has several LayoutRenderers that can be used to retrieve ASP.NET parameters, including UserIdentity.

Comment: To others who come after, this is now in NLog.Web, not NLog.Extended

Comment: what if `${aspnet-user-identity}` is empty ?! Can I assign `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` directly ?

Comment: The code behind `${aspnet-user-identity}` just retrieves `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, so I would not expect getting the name directly to yield anything different.

Comment: adding ${windows-identity} worked like charm for the windows identity

Comment: For some reason, this still doesnt work, using .netcore 2.2 web api, enabled windows authentication to the web api but it logs empty value. is this because, i also have the anonymous auth enabled?

Answer (score 3):

For those using custom `authentication`/`authorization` (or can't use the `windows` identity for some reason) and are using `.NET core` (`3.*`) you can use the `MappedDiagnosticsContext` to *inject* custom key-values.

As soon as you *know* the identity of the user you can set it like so:

```
using NLog;
//...
MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("UserName", "Some user name");
```

Always make sure you do this in a *Scoped* manner (using .NET core *Dependency Injection* terms, or a *Per Request Scope*), since you don't want to mix up users when logging.

In your `NLog` config you can then read the value by using this syntax `${mdc:UserName}`.

I'm using the following `nuget` packages:

- `nlog`
- `nlog.web.aspnetcore`

Comment: There's a renderer for this which works fine on Core 3.1 at least:
  <parameter name="@user" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}"/>

Answer (score 2):

NLog ver. 4.6.4 introduced `${environment-user}` that works on both Windows and Linux. It resolves to [System.Environment.UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username)

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-User-Layout-Renderer

For ASP.NET application there is also `${aspnet-user-identity}` for the user-identity currently logged on.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use Microsoft identity, so for adding username I just added it to the context in a middleware:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // ... Get UserName and store it to MyUserName

        context.Items.Add("UserName", MyUserName);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

then in NLog config I used `${aspnet-item:variable=UserName}` to render user name from context.