# how to log Environment.UserName in NLog?

Tags: nlog

how to log `Environment.UserName` in **NLog?** i have an application that works both on  window authentication and form authentication. So i need to log   `Environment.UserName` in my log file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add current user to NLog output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077958/add-current-user-to-nlog-output)

Answer (score 4):

NLog ver. 4.6.4 introduces `${environment-user}`.

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Environment-User-Layout-Renderer

Comment: This worked for me, since I wanted to get the application pool identity of my ASP.NET Core service in IIS, where previously I was getting the machine account with ${environment:Username}.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `${windows-identity}`, which uses  [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I'm unsure if that the same as `Environment.UserName`

Or (NLog 4.4+ needed)

```cs
//register at start of your program, main(), app_start etc
LayoutRenderer.Register("username", (logEvent) => Environment.UserName);
```

usage:

```
${username}
```

More info over ${windows-identity}, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Windows-Identity-Layout-Renderer